# PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.1.36ubuntu1 is an invalid version, has anyone seen this before

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pipenv

> /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:116:
> PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.1.36ubuntu1 is an invalid version
> and will not be supported in a future release

What is causing this, and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: did you get an answer to this by any other means, on a newly configured machine I'm seeing this when I do 'pipenv shell'.

Comment: It would be useful if the post included context, what you are trying to achieve instead, and what your question actually is.

Comment: I get something very similar to this in Windows as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message started to pop up for me once I've updated pip through itself. All it takes is uninstalling the initial pip version that was previously installed system-wide, which in my case, was obtained through the operating system's package manager e.g. APT.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error upon upgrading the Ubuntu version to 20.

Removing the the `python3-debian` package via `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python3-debian` worked for me.

Comment: There isn't a version of Ubuntu called "Ubuntu 20". Ubuntu versions look like 20.04 or 20.10 or 21.04 or 21.10 or 22.04, and so on. (The first number stands for the year, and the second number for the month). See [Ubuntu releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: Lots of essential packages like `update-notofier-common` depend on `python3-debian` in Ubuntu 22.04. Also, I'm still not sure how this will help solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

This appears to be an error in the following file: `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py`

and is possibly (probably) related to the `import _imp` statement(s) near the top of the file.

Comment: what you are seeing is most likely an artifact of the markdown renderer rather than a misnamed file. double underscore is __bold__

Comment: I fixed the formatting.